# UITextview write in Text Center Alignment , swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsmutablearray, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I have one Text Editor when I tap to Bold Button

I can write in Bold here is code

```
txtEditor.typingAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.black/, NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: (txtEditor.font?.pointSize)!)]
```

I want to have one button when I tap to Button (The Line who I write) I need to  in Centre Text Center Alignment and  not other Line before

here is code

```
let paragraph = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraph.alignment = .center
```

but after how will to add this 2 line code in UITextview for typing in Centre Alignment ?

Comment: What u want? textview centre alignment for text written inside text view?

Comment: @ShivamTripathi  Yes for example I write in left alignment after tap to this button I will write in centre alignment

Comment: @ShivamTripathi after tap to button I can type in centre Alignment

Comment: @ShivamTripathi Yes  , do you have any code ?

Answer (score 12):

Try this.

```
extension UITextView {

    func centerText() {
        self.textAlignment = .center
        let fittingSize = CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let size = sizeThatFits(fittingSize)
        let topOffset = (bounds.size.height - size.height * zoomScale) / 2
        let positiveTopOffset = max(1, topOffset)
        contentOffset.y = -positiveTopOffset
    }

}
```

use like this

```
@IBAction func btnClick(_ sender: Any) {
        textView.centerText()
    }
```

Comment: this code work for all string text view goes to Alignment centre I want some text say for example left alignment and when I tap the new text goes to centre

Comment: I need just the line who I wrote its one Center Alignment

Comment: Any UITextView have an attribute called "textAlignment" ... you only need to write this: "yourTextView.textAlignment = .center"

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4+

```swift
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) { textView.textAlignment = .center }
```